# Isolation Level in JMS

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, transactions, jms

Is there any transaction isolation level available in JMS queue like in [JDBC](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/jdbc-4_1-mrel-spec/index.html) ?

More specifically in transitional mode,  when a client consumes a message and has not committed yet, will the next client consume the next message? If the 1st client rolls back transition, where the message placed in the queue, I think  it will be placed where it was earlier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: **no**.

JMS sending is either transactional or not, which means the message is "committed" (visible for the broker and MDBs) when senders transaction commits or immediately (even if client sending transaction rollbacks later).

JMS receiving has simple on/off transactions as well: message is marked as received either when it's picked up by MDB (non-transactional) or when MDB returns without exception (transactional).

Comment: you mean message marked as received won't be available to any other consumer until rollback by the 1st consumer?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee: When transactional consumer receives message, this message can go back to the queue if consumer rolls back so that other consumer can retry. When non-transactional consumer receives message, it's removed completely from the queue and if consumer rolls back or throws an error, message is lost (won't be processed again)

Answer (score 0):

Transaction isolation is about visibility of DB table changes. JMS messages are immutable, you send it once and you cannot change it.

Comment: still in transitional mode, a consumer needs to commit/rollback explicitly, right? Is the uncommitted consumption by a client visible to the other?

Comment: ok. we can say there is only one level in JMS - read committed. how about that?